# What are all these Python files?

Tags: macos, python

What are the .py, .pyo, and .pyc files in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/X11/xcb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the Python bindings for X11. More info can be found in the [X11 Documentation](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/XcbPythonBinding/).

Comment: Interesting, you're the first Finnish person I've seen on here.

Comment: Really? Well in Finland everything always happens 10 years later ;)

Comment: Nice... Haha. I'm curious, how much does a Mac cost in Finland?

Comment: Well, we've got 23% VAT and all that, take a look in the [Finnish Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/fi) for exact prices.